# Setting up Statistics with litecoin-qt or bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-pools, litecoin, altcoin

I'm trying to set up a bitcoin/altcoin pool server, but I've run in to a bit of a problem, I have no way to verify I've connected to the pool succesfully, and no stats or informations on the actual pool operations. Is there some way I could find these stats in litecoin-qt or bitcoin-qt? The getinfo command seems to only return stats about the client, versus the actual pool info. I'd also like to have them generated automatically vs having to calculate myself.

Comment: Please provide more information. How long have you been a miner, how long have you know bitcoin/litecoin/altcoin? What are you using for your back end/frontend? either one should show you if you are on the right track. if you can provide this info i can help. I am a altcoin pool op for about a year now myself. *EDIT* are you using a front end?

Comment: @JoeWhite Updated and no I don't believe I am using a frontend, though I'm not sure what it is. I'm just trying to start, but now that I think about it, I have heard about frontends before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dylan, i suggest you do a lot more reading before you attempt to run a pool. A pool is not an easy job, you need an in-depth knowledge of bitcoin/c++/python etc. It's not simply cut and paste.

Unfourtunately from waht i am reading you are only running a coin daemon as your pool node which won't work for a pool. check out how to install mmcfe for litecoin. that should help you out

Comment: I know c++, and python, I'm currently learning quite alot about bitcoins. Thank you for putting me on the right track, though I think you underestimate me.
EDIT: Also does pushpool work for this?

Comment: Dylan, i'm sorry if you got the opinion that i underestimate you. I do not know you more than your post here and you said some odd phrasing "but now that I think about it, I have heard about frontends before" so I just have to assume that you are not knowledgeable about it. I just don't want to see you have any problems with your code. please feel free to contact me with any help you may need.

Comment: yeah pusphool does work, but not sure why you would want that. stratum is much better. https://github.com/moopless/stratum-mining-litecoin

*EDIT* or mpos https://github.com/TheSerapher/php-mpos